# Characters other than 0-9 A-F in Pythons Bytes Hex Format

Tags: python, hex, byte

I am playing with the [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) and wanting to start from the raw IDX format files. I am using Python version `3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]`.

I read the data in as bytes:

```
with open('t10k-images-idx3-ubyte', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

and then start looking at the bytes, four at a time, and start comparing them to the hex signature values on the MNIST website.

```
data[0:4]
>>> b'\x00\x00\x08\x03'   # (good so far)

data[4:8]
>>> b"\x00\x00'\x10"      # (not sure why there's this single quote / apostrophe character)
```

I know from the website this value should be 10000, so I run this code next:

```
int.from_bytes(data[4:8], 'big')
>>> 10000
```

So that's the right value, but the hex for this should be `b"\x00\x27\x10"`

I prove that as well with this:

```
int.from_bytes(b"\x00\x27\x10", 'big')
>>> 10000
```

At this point I'm very confused, so I google the ascii table to check what value the single quote apostrophe character is. Sure enough, it's `27`.

**TLDR: Why does Python give me a character other than 0-9 or A-F for hex code representation of bytes? Is this a bug or is there something else going on?**

Also, I'm using Jupyter notebooks as well - so not sure if that matters.

Comment: Python represents ascii characters as themselves in bytes: `b'\x00\x27\x00' == b"\x00'\x00"`

Comment: Yes, thank you. That post/thread does answer my question. I wasn't able to find that one through search. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytes are there. But most printable ASCII characters don't have to be displayed with an escape code. Does this help clarify?

```
>>> hex(b"\x00\x00'\x10"[2])
'0x27'
```

The code above accesses the third element of the bytes with `[2]`, just like a list, and then renders it as a string in hexadecimal format using the builtin `hex()` function. Here's another example.

```
>>> b"B"[0]
66
>>> hex(66)
'0x42'
>>> b'\x42'
b'B'
```